# Can we match an exact string using html pattern attribute only?

Tags: regex, html, validation

Lets get to the problem as I allow open registration on my website(any one can open registration page) but I want only those people able to proceed who have a specific code (like "CDCode"). This is in a form and I want to check it on form Submit.

I know it is possible with onfocusout but javascript can be disabled so not a perfect solution.

I want some solution with pure HTML like with pattern attribute. So anyhow we can make pattern attribute match an exact string?

Comment: `pattern="CDCode"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="test" pattern="CDCode" >
```

Comment: An empty input seems to pass this validation. How do you make it required?

Comment: You can add `required` attribute

Comment: Not working for <select> in chrome currently it seems